# Exim force NON-TLS for a certain relay host

Tags: exim, tls

I have to relay mail to a certain host that advertises TLS but the remote host falls over.  How can I add something to my router that forces the router not to use TLS.  This is my route

```
send_to_gateway:
    driver = manualroute
    domains = ! +relay_to_domains
    transport = remote_smtp
    route_list = * smtp.example.com
    no_more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be done at the transport level, add this to your remote_smtp

```
hosts_avoid_tls = ip_of_smtp_example_com
```